# Pass value from c# to cshtml to TypeScript

Tags: asp.net-mvc, typescript, razor

I have a project where I am passing the data from C# to cshtml by something like this:

```
public IActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewData["temp"] = "abc"
        return View();
    }
```

This value is then received in the cshtml file where I can read this as

```
var temp = ViewData["temp"];
```

I have a typescript file that is then booted from this cshtml file.
My question is, how can I use this temp variable in my typescript code. I don't want to create a 'div' element for this temp data and then read its value in typescript as this will not be a clean thing to do from security perspective.

Can you please suggest some way to do it in a proper way?

Answer (score 4):

In your view returned by the `Index` action just choose an existing element (you can choose the `body` element if your view contain it) and in that element add an `data-*` attribute (you can name it `data-temp`) like below :

```
<SomeElementInMyView data-temp="@temp">...</SomeElementInMyView>
```

In your Typescript file, I suppose you're using jQuery so get the data value like this:

```
let dataTemp = $("SomeElementInMyView").data("temp");
```

Comment: Even if I do this, the data-temp value is visible in the page's DOM tree. Is there some way we can hide it from the DOM tree?

Comment: No. If you need your data from Razor Page to be accessible into your typescript/javascript file you must put it into the DOM file. Typescript/javascript file then inspect the DOM and get the data. This is the good practice.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass it as string variable in html eg.

```
let typeScriptVariable: string = "@temp";
```